# Filter Search List without word order

Tags: javascript

```js
function myFunction() {

  var filter = $('input').val().toUpperCase().split(' ');
  var li = $('li');
  var a = $('a');
  var ul;
  var txtValue;
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    for (var f = 0; f < filter.length; f++) {
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter[f]) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = '';
        // don't need further matches
      } else {
        li[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 650px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.homework {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.responsive {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

a.responsive2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

i.fa-video {
  color: black;
  animation-name: changecolor;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes changecolor {
  from {
    color: black;
  }
  to {
    color: red;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}


/* On screens that are 992px wide or less, the background color is blue */

@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .responsive {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  a.responsive2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}


/* On screens that are 600px wide or less, the background color is olive */

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  a.responsive2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 75px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .close {
    color: black;
  }
  .homework {
    padding-left: 0px!important;
  }
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 9999;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 10px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  z-index: 9999;
  height: auto;
}

#caption2 {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption,
#caption2 {
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption,
#caption2 {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 15px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.w3-sidebar a {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif
}

body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
.w3-wide {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.homework {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.responsive {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

a.responsive2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

i.fa-video {
  color: black;
  animation-name: changecolor;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes changecolor {
  from {
    color: black;
  }
  to {
    color: red;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}


/* On screens that are 992px wide or less, the background color is blue */

@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .responsive {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  a.responsive2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
}


/* On screens that are 600px wide or less, the background color is olive */

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  a.responsive2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 75px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .close {
    color: black;
  }
  
  }
  .homework {
    padding-left: 0px!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="w3-hide-large" style="margin-top:83px"></div>

<div class="w3-row" style="border: 3px solid black;">
  <div class=" w3-white w3-text-black w3-container" style="height: auto; padding: 0.1em 0px;">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Moteur de rechecher.." title="Type in a name">
    <div class="w3-padding-64">

    </div>

    <ul id="myUL">
      <div>
        <li>
          <div id="caption2" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a style="color: black;"> <strong> Complexes AG2019 </strong> TS QCM Bac </a>
          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
          <img src="images/AG2019TS.png" alt="Complexes AG2019 TS QCM  Bac" id="myImg" class="w3-button w3-hover-blue-grey " style="width:100%;max-width:70px;display: inline-block;">
          <a href="videos/AG19 complexes test1.mp4"><span class="responsive">Corrigé <i class='fas fa-video'></i></span></a></li>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
          <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <li>
          <div id="caption2" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a style="color: black;"> <strong> Complexes Liban </strong> 2019 TS Bac </a>
          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
          <img src="images/Li19 TS complexes.png" alt="Complexes Liban 2019 TS Bac" id="myImg2" class="w3-button w3-hover-blue-grey " style="width:100%;max-width:70px;display: inline-block;">
          <a href="videos/AG19 complexes test1.mp4"><span class="responsive">Corrigé <i class='fas fa-video' ></i></span></a></li>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img02">
          <div id="caption2"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div>
        <li>
          <div id="caption2" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a style="color: black;"> <strong> Fonction exponentielle </strong> Asie19 TS Bac </a>
          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
          <img src="images/Fonction exponentielle Asie19 TS Bac.png" alt="Fonction exponentielle Asie19 TS Bac" id="myImg3" class="w3-button w3-hover-blue-grey " style="width:100%;max-width:70px;display: inline-block;">
          <a href="videos/AG19 complexes test1.mp4"><span class="responsive">Corrigé <i class='fas fa-video' ></i></span></a></li>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal3" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img03">
          <div id="caption3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div>
        <li>
          <div id="caption2" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a style="color: black;"> <strong> Suite geometrique </strong> Asie2019 TS Bac </a>
          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
          <img src="images/Suite geometrique Asie2019 TS.png" alt="Suite geometrique Asie2019 TS" id="myImg4" class="w3-button w3-hover-blue-grey " style="width:100%;max-width:70px;display: inline-block;">
          <a href="videos/AG19 complexes test1.mp4"><span class="responsive">Corrigé <i class='fas fa-video' ></i></span></a></li>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal4" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img04">
          <div id="caption4"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <li>
          <div id="caption2" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a style="color: black;"> <strong> Fonction logarihtme avec suites  </strong> AN2019 TS Bac </a>
          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
          <img src="images/fonction logarihtme avec suites AN2019 TS Bac.jpg" alt="fonction logarihtme avec suites AN2019 TS Bac" id="myImg5" class="w3-button w3-hover-blue-grey " style="width:100%;max-width:70px;display: inline-block;">
          <a href="videos/AG19 complexes test1.mp4"><span class="responsive">Corrigé <i class='fas fa-video' ></i></span></a></li>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal5" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img05">
          <div id="caption5"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div>
        <li>
          <div id="caption2" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a style="color: black;"> <strong> Fonction logarihtme </strong> Li2019 TS Bac </a>
          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
          <img src="images/fonction logarithme Li2019 TS Bac.png" alt="fonction logarithme Li2019 TS Bac" id="myImg6" class="w3-button w3-hover-blue-grey " style="width:100%;max-width:70px;display: inline-block;">
          <a href="videos/AG19 complexes test1.mp4"><span class="responsive">Corrigé <i class='fas fa-video' ></i></span></a></li>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal6" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img06">
          <div id="caption6"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div>
        <li>
          <div id="caption2" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a style="color: black;"> <strong> Géométrie avec coordonnées </strong> Li2019 TS Bac </a>
          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
          <img src="images/Geometrie avec coordonnees Li2019 TS Bac.png" alt="Géométrie avec coordonnées Li2019 TS Bac" id="myImg7" class="w3-button w3-hover-blue-grey " style="width:100%;max-width:70px;display: inline-block;">
          <a href="videos/AG19 complexes test1.mp4"><span class="responsive">Corrigé <i class='fas fa-video' ></i></span></a></li>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal7" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img07">
          <div id="caption7"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div>
        <li>
          <div id="caption2" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a style="color: black;"> <strong>Géométrie sans coordonnées </strong> Li2019 TS Bac </a>
          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
          <img src="images/Geometrie sans coordonnees Li2019 TS Bac.png" alt="Géométrie sans coordonnées Li2019 TS Bac" id="myImg8" class="w3-button w3-hover-blue-grey " style="width:100%;max-width:70px;display: inline-block;">
          <a href="videos/AG19 complexes test1.mp4"><span class="responsive">Corrigé <i class='fas fa-video' ></i></span></a></li>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal8" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img08">
          <div id="caption8"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div>
        <li>
          <div id="caption2" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a style="color: black;"> <strong>Probabilités conditionnelles </strong> AG2019juin TS bac </a>
          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
          <img src="images/Probabilites conditionnelles AG2019juin TS bac.png" alt="Probabilités conditionnelles AG2019juin TS bac" id="myImg9" class="w3-button w3-hover-blue-grey " style="width:100%;max-width:70px;display: inline-block;">
          <a href="videos/AG19 complexes test1.mp4"><span class="responsive">Corrigé <i class='fas fa-video' ></i></span></a></li>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal9" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img09">
          <div id="caption9"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div>
        <li>
          <div id="caption2" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a style="color: black;"> <strong>Probabilités conditionnelles </strong> AN2019 TS bac </a>
          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
          <img src="images/Probabilites conditionnelles AN2019 TS bac.jpg" alt="Probabilites conditionnelles AN2019 TS bac" id="myImg10" class="w3-button w3-hover-blue-grey " style="width:100%;max-width:70px;display: inline-block;">
          <a href="videos/AG19 complexes test1.mp4"><span class="responsive">Corrigé <i class='fas fa-video' ></i></span></a></li>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal10" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img10">
          <div id="caption10"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div>
        <li>
          <div id="caption2" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a style="color: black;"> <strong>Probabilités conditionnelles avec suites </strong> Li2019 TS bac </a>
          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
          <img src="images/Probabilites conditionnelles avec suites Li2019 TS bac.png" alt="Probabilites conditionnelles avec suites Li2019 TS bac" id="myImg11" class="w3-button w3-hover-blue-grey " style="width:100%;max-width:70px;display: inline-block;">
          <a href="videos/AG19 complexes test1.mp4"><span class="responsive">Corrigé <i class='fas fa-video' ></i></span></a></li>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="myModal11" class="modal">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <img class="modal-content" id="img11">
          <div id="caption11"></div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </ul>
```

I want to perform a filtered list search that it does not require words to be in order. I fixed that however new problems came up. If I type in the code snippet below Complex Bac for example it will show all the results that have Bac in it , regardless if I want results that have Complex and Bac combined.

```
     function myFunction() {

var filter =  $('input').val().toUpperCase().split(' ');
var li = $('li');
var a = $('a');
var ul;
var txtValue;
ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    for(var f = 0; f < filter.length; f++) {
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter[f]) > -1 ) {    
            li[i].style.display = '';
           // don't need further matches
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I've already followed these steps , but I did not find a solution . I exhausted all options , I googled a lot about this .

Comment: But what have you tried yourself? Posting a snippet from w3schools doesn't demonstrate any real work on your own. How do you think you would solve it? What does it mean for words to match, precisely. Would "p**HOT**ographed` boon**DOG**gle" match? How about "et**H**n**O**me**T**ho**DO**lo**G**y"?

Comment: Thanks again for the reply ! I've already handled this issue with the case sensitivity. My issue is that the search doesn't show results if the words are not typed in the same order as in the list . If we have a big list of foods and I want to search for the word "Hot Dog" , it will show the result of I type "hot dog " but it won't show anything if I search for "dog hot"

Comment: I wasn't demonstrating case-sensitivity but words that contain "HOT" and "DOG" or just the letters H, O, T, D, O, and G in order.  I was trying to prompt you into thinking about your fundamental requirements, so that you could take a first stab at this yourself.  People really are willing to help, but ideally we'd like to see your attempts first.

Comment: I could split all my input strings on spaces and return values that contain either all or any of the input words . What is your view on this ?

Comment: That sounds like a very good approach!  There's an `edit` link at the bottom of your question.  Could  you update with an attempt to do that, and with a description of where you get stuck... if you do?

Comment: I updated it but it doesn't work . Sorry if I'm becoming annoying but I'm very new to JS . To illustrate my problem better here is a video .  https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/26569942/56949597-f8f6f280-6b50-11e9-8521-bfd1235126d9.gif

Comment: As I said the last time, edit the question to share the code you're working with.  I understand the requirements, and have ideas of how to do it.  But StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.  We want to help, but not to simply do the work for you.  I'm guessing that if you include your current code, someone can show you what's wrong.

Comment: @ScottSauyet  Hey I updated the code and I made it work ! However , new problem have came up. If I have the list items Hot Dog and Brown Dog for instance , if I search for " Dog Hot " , it will now show the list item Hot Dog -which is nice- but it will also show the list item Brown Dog. I don't want this to happen. Any ideas?

Comment: As I've said several times now, you need to post the code you're working on.  Then people may be able to help

Comment: @ScottSauyet Hey sorry for bothering again , I edited it once again and now I think it is runnable. My problem is that , althought my search bar can now search irrespectively of word order , it will now show a broad range of results. Specifically , if I type Complex Bac , it will show all the list items which contain the word Bac in it , regardless if Complex exists or not. I dont want this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

```js
const phones = [
  "Galaxy Note 3",
  "Galaxy S5",
  "Microsoft Lumia 950",
  "Pixel 2",
  "Kindle Fire HDX",
  "iPad Mini",
  "Samsung Metro",
];
const input = document.getElementById('input')
const ul = document.getElementById("myUL");

input.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const {
    value
  } = e.target

  if (value === '') ul.innerHTML = ''
  else {
    const match = phones.filter(tag => tag.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
    ul.innerHTML = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
      ul.innerHTML += `<li>${match[i]}</li>`
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="seach for phone..">
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply ! I've tested the code but unfortunately it doesn't provide the desired result. I want my search to give results irrespectively of the word order . My problem is very well illustrated in this short gif . https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/26569942/56949597-f8f6f280-6b50-11e9-8521-bfd1235126d9.gif

Comment: Hi Alex, Do you mean something like [this](https://codepen.io/awran5/pen/YzXGBRz)?

Comment: @awran5: I think the point is that when the user types "new jersey" it should have matches, but also when she types "jersey new".

Comment: @ScottSauyet I got it wrong then. Actually I'm a bit confused, the snippet he has included in the question will do the trick?

Comment: @awran5: No, that's why I keep pushing for code that's actually attempting to solve the issue.  I can write it; in fact I just altered yours to do this, but I want to see a real attempt before adding a solution.  Just trying to show a newcomer the norms here.

Comment: @ScottSauyet That's cool man :) go ahead and add your answer, I edited mine though ^^

Comment: @ScottSauyet  Hey I updated the code and I made it work ! However , new problem have came up. If I have the list items Hot Dog and Brown Dog for instance , if I search for " Dog Hot " , it will now show the list item Hot Dog -which is nice- but it will also show the list item Brown Dog. I don't want this to happen. Any ideas?